# Equivalence of Categories Lemma Explanation

Tags: category-theory

In the image below, I am unable to understand the following points in Lemma 1.5.1:
1. Why do we need $C \times 2$ as the domain of functor H? 
2. What does "$H$ restricts along $i_0$ and $i_1$ to the functors $F$ and $G$" mean?
3. How do we get a bijection between a **natural transformation** and **functor** $H$?

[image: Equivalence of Categories]

Comment: Can you provide some background knowledge? Where did you get the lemma? What is your background knowledge? Without this information it could be difficult providing a satisfying answer.

Comment: The lemma is from Section 1.5 "Equivalence of Categories" from "Category Theory in Context" by Emily Riehl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you are familiar with homotopies between continuous maps. If not, I suggest you try to understand that concept first and then try to understand this analogy.

To talk about the analogy let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and $f,g\colon X\to Y$ continuous maps. Let $F\colon X\times I\to Y$ be an homotopy between them, that is a continuous map such that $F|_{X\times \{ 0\}}=f$ and $F|_{X\times \{ 1\}}=g$.

1. In the analogy, just as before we had $X\times I$ as the domain of our homotopy $F$, now we will have $C\times \mathbb{2}$ as the domain of our "homotopy-functor" $H$.
2. This means precisely what is written in the diagram below, and the word *restricts* is justified precisely by this analogy, in which $F$ does really restrict to $f$ on $X\times \{ 0\}$ and to $g$ on $X\times \{ 1\}$. Note that in the topological case you can also express this with a very similar diagram, namely using bottom and top inclusions $i_{0},i_{1}\colon X \to X\times I$.
3. The bijection is a nice and easy exercise that I don't want to spoil. Just write down what everything is and you will see how to assign to each natural transformation $\alpha$ such a functor $H$ and vice versa. **Hints**: objects are easy. For morphisms, note that there are 3 cases: $f\times \rightarrow $, $f\times id_{0}$ or $f\times id_{1}$ for some morphism $f$ in $C$. The last two cases are easy because you know that they must be the corresponding functor $F$ or $G$. For the first case use (resp. define) the natural transformation through its component at the domain of $f$ and then compose with the morphism corresponding to the naturality condition. To make it more intuitive, think of the map $f\times \rightarrow \colon (c_{1},0) \to (c_{2},1)$ as the composition
   $$(c_{1},0)\to (c_{1},1) \to (c_{2},1)$$

Comment: Thanks for the Homotopy analogy! I didn't think about it that way. But now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this question has an already accepted answer, nevertheless allow me to add something here.

> 2. What does "$H$ restricts along $i_0$ and $i_1$ to the functors $F$ and $G$" mean?

It means that the composites $H \circ i_0$ and $H \circ i_1$ are equal to $F$ and $G$ respectively (that is the two triangles in the diagram commutes).

> 1. Why do we need $C \times 2$ as the domain of functor $H$?

That is probably the hardest point to answer. Observe that if the $H$ restricts to $F$ and $G$ through the $i_j$'s then for each object $c \in C$ you have the morphism 
$$(c,0) \longrightarrow (c,1)$$ whose image through $H$ provide you with a morphism
$$F(c)=H(c,0) \longrightarrow H(c,1)=G(c)$$
whose source and target coincie with those of the $c$-component of a natural transformation.

On the other hand for every $f \in C[c,c']$ you have a commutative square
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
(c,0) @>>> (c,1) \\
@V(f,\text{id}_0)VV       @VV(f,\text{id}_1)V \\
(c',0) @>>> (c',1)
\end{CD}
$$
This square is send via $H$ into the square
$$\begin{CD}
F(c)=H(c,0) @>>> H(c,1)=G(c) \\
@V{F(f)=H(f,\text{id}_0)}VV             @VV{H(f,\text{id}_1)=G(f)}V \\
F(c')=H(c',0) @>>>   H(c',1)=G(c') 
\end{CD}$$
which is a naturality square.

So as you can see the images of the morphisms $(c,0) \to (c,1)$ via $H$ forms the components if natural transformations. This happens because $C \times 2$ has enough structure to build the above mentioned square.

Of course there is a deeper reason for why this works, namely that $2$ is the *classifying object for the morphisms of a category*, that means that there is a *natural* bijection between functors from $2$ in a category $C$ and morphisms of $C$. But that is a story for another day.

At this point I hope that the answer to

> 3. How do we get a bijection between a **natural transformation** and **functor** $H$
>      can be easily guessed.

Feel free to ask for any additonal detail.